# HTML5 Canvas with jCanvas: How to remove a layer

Tags: html, canvas, jcanvas

I am using jCanvas to build a HTML5 app, I need to remove a layer, which is a black circle on the canvas, you can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LAbXg/2/).

```
var cvLingualWidth = 945;
var cvLingualHeight = 100;

var cvLingual = document.getElementById("cvLingual");

function drawGrid() {
    var contextLingual = cvLingual.getContext("2d");

    for (var y = 0.5; y < cvLingualHeight; y += 6) {
        contextLingual.moveTo(0, y);
        contextLingual.lineTo(cvLingualWidth, y);
    }

    contextLingual.strokeStyle = "#DDD";
    contextLingual.stroke();
}

function drawCircle() {
    $("#cvLingual").drawArc({
        layer: true,
        name: "circleLayer_18",
        strokeStyle: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        x: 42,
        y: 70,
        radius: 8
    });
}

function clearCircle() {
    var circleLayer = $("#cvLingual").getLayer("circleLayer_18");
    // TODO
}

$(function () {
    drawGrid();
    drawCircle();
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        clearCircle();
    });
})
```

I tried removeLayer() but its not working. If I clear the canvas, the entire UI will be gone.

How can I clear the circle without affecting the background gridlines?

Comment: @Innovation Why? jCanvas is extremely powerful and completely supports what he's trying to do. Plus, he's already using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [`removeLayer()` documentation](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/manipulateLayers/#removing-layers), the `removeLayer()` method does not update the canvas automatically. You will need to do this afterwards using the `drawLayers()` method.

```
$("#cvLingual").removeLayer("myLayer").drawLayers();
```

*However*, the `drawLayers()` method works by clearing the canvas and redrawing all jCanvas layers, which means that your gridlines will disappear. To fix this, use jCanvas's `drawLine()` method to draw your gridlines, like so:

```
$canvas.drawLine({
    layer: true,
    strokeStyle: "#DDD",
    strokeWidth: 1,
    x1: 0, y1: y,
    x2: cvLingualWidth, y2: y
});
```

As a side note, if you are planning on drawing the circle again later (*after* removing it), I recommend setting the layer's `visible` property to `false` temporarily. Then, when you are ready to show the circle again, set its `visible` property to `true`. Note that you will need to call `drawLayers()` to update the canvas in both instances.

*Hide the circle:*

```
$("#cvLingual").setLayer({
    visible: false
}).drawLayers();
```

*Show the circle again:*

```
$("#cvLingual").setLayer({
    visible: true
}).drawLayers();
```

Finally, for your convenience, I have [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3emk2/2/) and have implemented the above suggestions.